# Как получить флаг с кавычками из командной строки

Tags: строки, golang

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу корректно получать аргумент

```
option = flag.String("option", `None`, "set option")
flag.Parse()
fmt.Println(*option)
```

допустим, при запуске я указываю `go run client.go -option {"op":"ping"}`. Но `fmt.Println` выводит без кавычек, т.е `{op:ping}`.

Как мне получить аргумент в исходном его виде?

Comment: Дык консоль кавычки съедает. `-option '{"op":"ping"}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большинство терминалов считают кавычки спец. символами. Используйте единичные кавычки чтобы экранировать двойные:

```
$ go run client.go -option '{"op":"ping"}'
```